# UILabel selected in a multiple option quiz template

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uilabel

I am a newbie, and trying to create  a multiple-option quiz. I've created the options as labels, the structure is working so far.

I would like to have the label get highlighted upon tap..
I've tried changing the font color, etc... but nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UILabel` is not a subclass of `UIControl` which gives you the inherited functionality that you want. You would be better of doing this with buttons as they are subclasses of `UIControl`. You can make a button that appears just as text like you described above.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I agree with Mike, but I implemented the Label in a slightly different way. I just used the 'option1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;' and then implemented the 'touchesBegan' function to get it working.         Will this create problems eventually??

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll get more helpful answers if you show your code.
2. You should probably be using UIButton instead of UILabel. UILabel isn't a control and isn't really designed for interaction.
3. After changing attributes of a view like UILabel, you may need to call `-setNeedsDisplay` to get it to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to put a UIButton over your UILabel, and set the type to custom. This will make it invisible to the user. Then you can wire the button's touch up inside event to a method and change the styling of your UILabel from there.